# Filter Date and Time in MS SQL Server used for Date Range filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

What is the correct Date Format should I use in MS SQL Server if I have this kind of scenario?

```
--This values here will be supplied by a datetimepicker Control
@StartDate = '05/15/2013 10:00 PM' 
@EndDate = '05/16/2013 06:00 AM'

SELECT * 
FROM tblSomething 
WHERE TransDate >= @StartDate AND TransDate <= @EndDate
```

How can I format the TransDate field?

Is this Correct?

```
Declare @StartDate as datetime
Declare @EndDate as datetime

set @StartDate = '05/15/2013 10:00 PM'
set @EndDate = '05/16/2013 06:00 AM'


Select * from tblSomething Where convert(varchar(20),TransDate,100) >= convert(varchar(20),@StartDate,100) and convert(varchar(20),TransDate,100) <= convert(varchar(20),@EndDate,100)
```

The reason AM/PM is important to me is because we have employees that have transactions that starts 10PM in the evening and ends at 6am the next morning. I need to extract the transactions of that employee with that time frame.

Comment: Format the transdate field? What datatype is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to think about date formats at all, you're doing it wrong.

The DateTimePicker control gives you a value of the .Net DateTime type. Your TransDate column should be a Sql Server DateTime type, as should your @StartDate and @EndDate parameters. At no point should you *ever* need to express any of these as a string. They should always be a binary format that isn't even human readable. If you've done this, the select query as written should do what you need.

Here's an example (C#, can do VB if you'd prefer) of how all this might work:

```c
//imaginary function to check if there's at least one record in the data range
bool CheckDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //sql is unchanged from your question
    string sql = "Select * from tblSomething Where TransDate >=  @StartDate  AND TransDate <= @EndDate";

     using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
     {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

        cn.Open()
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           //all we care is whether there's at least one row
           // there is a row if and only if .Read() succeeds
           return rdr.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

You could call it like this:

```c
//hopefully you picked better control names :)
if (CheckDates(dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value))
{
   //do something
}
```

The important thing is that at no point anywhere do you ever convert that DateTime to a string.

Comment: Yes my TransDate field is a DateTime data type. The AM/PM is very important to me. I will give it a try. Tnx

Comment: Just to complement your excellent answer, the only time one should be dealing with a date string is for input and output.  For example,  in your control when entering/picking a date, and in the display when outputting a date.  And there, you need to be very careful to use the correct locale.  But once it's a date, never treat it as a string.

Comment: Sorry the solution above returns zero result set.

Comment: @user2059064 Well of course: it doesn't even try to read any results. It's just an example of how to use the parameters. If you want a more detailed solution, we need more detailed info... like a set of sample data and some example searches on the sample with expected results.

Comment: If I use these paramaters '05/15/2013' and '05/16/2013' SQL server will give me a result set. But if I use these parameters '05/15/2013 10:00 PM' and '05/16/2013 06:00 AM' I get zero results. The reason AM/PM is important to me is because we have employees that have transactions that starts 10PM in the evening and ends at 6am the next morning. I need to extract the transactions of that employee with that time frame.

Comment: You likely have a transaction occurring before 10:00PM on the 15th. Also check your time zones. You may be inadvertently storing or sending UTC data instead of local time data.

Comment: I think I have issues with my TransDate field. It used to have a smalldatetime data type and I changed it to datetime data type aftwerwards. Maybe that's why I get zero results. I tested the solution above with my other tables and it worked.

Comment: Or if you prefer >> 

DbResult dbResult = ExecuteCommand(
    sqlString,
    new SqlParameter[] {
        new SqlParameter("@startDay", startDateTime),
        new SqlParameter("@endDay", endDateTime)
    },
    false
);